# Unknown extensions in google protocol buffers

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

How to access Unknown extensions in google protocol buffers?

Known extension can be accessed by FindKnownExtensionByName using Reflections.

Similarly UnknownFieldSet() gives the unknown fields in the messsages.

So do we have any method to access Unknown extensions in google protocol buffers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unknown extensions will also appear in UnknownFieldSet.

Extensions are encoded exactly the same as regular fields -- the extension number is the field number. So if the parser sees a field on the wire which is not defined as either a field or an extension, it actually doesn't even know which it is. So, everything goes into UnknownFieldSet.